# Setting Spinner to the same layout as the XML version

Tags: android, spinner

In my source code I have two Spinner views, one is loaded using the entries attribute in the XML file, the other through an ArrayAdapter. I like how the layout of the version in the XML looks, when clicked it has a radio selection type look. I set the layout file of the ArrayAdapter to simple_spinner_item. Before selecting the spinner in the app, the two spinners look identical. When selected though it's just a simple and pretty small list, barely even big enough to click an item from. How do I change it to be like the entries one?

Comment: Can yo post some of your code where the spinners are populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize it with the [ArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setDropDownViewResource%28int%29) method:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Alright thanks for pointing that out, still new to this site. Loving the help from here though. :)